# Wrap element to new line/row using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have trouble forcing an item into the next row in a flexbox layout.

How can I do something like the following image?

[image]

This is what I got so far:

```css
#wrap {
  display: flex;
  width: 86vw;
  height: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.item1,
.item2 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 24.5vw;
  background: #4add69;
}
.item1 {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.item2 {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.item3 {
  width: 60%;
  height: 40vw;
  background: #d56c6c;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div class="item1"></div>
  <div class="item2"></div>
  <div class="item3"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your code is fine but missing two things.

1. Use [`flex-wrap: wrap`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-wrap/) to
   create a new row. Modify the width of the first two items to be
   present in a single row.
2. For the last two items, you need to nest it inside a container and
   then wrap them again.

Manipulate the dimension(width, height) and margin values to achieve the perfect/suitable layout.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Manojkr/hqgx0ua8/)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  background: #232323;
  padding: 10px;
}
#wrap {
  display: flex;
  width: 86vw;
  height: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 auto;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: #232323;
  /* Added */
}
.item1,
.item2 {
  width: 48%;
  /* Modified */
  height: 24.5vw;
  background: #4add69;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.item1 {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.item2 {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.item3 {
  width: 55%;
  height: 40vw;
  background: #d56c6c;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.nested-items {
  display: flex;
  width: 42%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: space-between;
}
.item4,
.item5 {
  background: lightblue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 49%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div class="item1"></div>
  <div class="item2"></div>
  <div class="item3"></div>
  <div class="nested-items">
    <div class="item4"></div>
    <div class="item5"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Essentially you need an extra wrapping div for the two 'small' elements like so:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrap {
  width: 75%;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: .25em;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.wrap div {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}
.box {
  height: 80px;
  background: lightblue;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}
.tall {
  flex: 0 0 65%;
  height: 160px;
}
.col {
  flex: 0 0 35%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.mini {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box tall"></div>
  <div class="box col">
    <div class="mini"></div>
    <div class="mini"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've used a single overall element here with wrapping but the image suggests that this would be much simpler with actual rows and the extra wrapper mentioned before.

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/yYOYBN) of 2nd option with rows.